# Why can I not mock a function called by an onClick event with Jest/Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a clickable component that looks as follows:

```
export default class Clickable extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(){
    console.log('clicked');
  }

  render(){
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}></button>
  }


}
```

I have confirmed in the browser that the onClick event is firing and calling the handle click function. However, I cannot get my test (jest/enzyme) to mock the click event. My test looks as follows.

```
describe("<Clickable/>", () => {
  let clickMock = jest.fn();
  let component = shallow(<Clickable/>);

  it("should call handleClick() when clicked on", () => {
    component.instance().handleClick = clickMock;
    component.update();
    component.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(clickMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

The test returns `Expected mock function to have been called.`

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you check if the `clickMock` was called?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part. I have edited the post. Still receive the same "Expect mock function to be called" failure from jest.

Comment: Long story: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/944

Answer (score -1):

try it:

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Foo from "path/Foo"

describe("Executes a handler function", () => {
  it("must call the mock method with button click", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Foo />);
    const button = wrapper.find("button");
    const instance = wrapper.instance();

    instance.btnClick = jest.fn(instance.btnClick);

    button.simulate("click");
    expect(instance.btnClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.